# What kind of speech is sentence final 〜なも associated with?

Tags: words, dialects

In the game どうぶつの森, the character たぬきち ends most of his sentences with 〜なも, for instance:

[image: Image from https://ga-m.com/n/atumare-doubutu-no-mori-black-settei-nihon-yami/]

Is this a characteristic of any real dialect or demographic, or just a 口癖 specific to the game?

Answer (score 2):

なも was a real dialectal sentence-ender used in Aichi. I have never seen real people who use it, though.

- [名古屋人はもう「～なも」とは言わない？ 代表的名古屋弁「絶滅」の真偽は...](https://j-town.net/tokyo/column/gotochicolumn/214466.html?p=all)
- [名古屋弁「～なも」なんて地元でほぼ使わないし**どっかの森のキャラ**しか浮かばない](https://togetter.com/li/891335)
- [～なも！という言葉は、どのあたりの方言なのでしょうか？](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1425568519)

There's even a [character called だなも](https://chara.yapy.jp/chara/danamo/).

ぞなもし is a variation used in Ehime: [愛媛県には、誰もが知っているが誰も使わない伝説の方言がある](https://matome.naver.jp/odai/2142798674976757501)

Basically it's just a rare [キャラ語尾](https://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E8%AA%9E%E5%B0%BE%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%80%E8%A6%A7), so few people care.

Comment: https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1425568519 has some detail about the role of 〜なも in Nagoya dialect. Sounds like it was already pretty rare in years gone by, and is vaguely remembered in the present day but not in current use.