# Particles じぇ and じょ

Tags: particles, dialects, sentence-final-particles

I am currently reading the manga 「咲」and the character 片{かた}岡{おか}優{ゆう}希{き} regularly ends her sentences with じょ and じぇ. I will give a few examples (each line isn't related to the next)

> 学食でタコス買ってきたじぇー
>
> のどちゃんはホントにすごいんだじょ!
>
> のどちゃんやっぱ強すぎたじぇ
>
> そうだじょ

What exactly does this mean? Is it a dialectical thing? I don't think this is a "pronounce ぞ/ぜ as じょ/じぇ" since she is shown pronouncing ぜ in words that require it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

じょ used to be a very common sentence-ender in Awa (Tokushima) dialect, although it's becoming obsolete, like other dialects. Looks like じぇ is a sentence-ender in Iwate dialect.

That being said, this character's speech is not dialectal at all, so basically this is just another unique [キャラ語尾](https://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E8%AA%9E%E5%B0%BE%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%80%E8%A6%A7) used to add flavor to a character.

Some キャラ語尾 are "recycled" ones taken from real but minor dialects. For example, [なも](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/76734/5010) is originally from Nagoya dialect and [だっちゃ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lum_Invader) is from Sendai dialect, but the famous users of them in fiction speak basically standard Japanese except for these 語尾's.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a mix of the two: a "dialectical" (or perhaps just personal) "pronounce ぞ/ぜ as じょ/じぇ" thing (but only specifically for the sentence-ending particles).

I feel like, in fictional media like video games, manga, and anime, sentence-enders are the very first thing that gets "tweaked" to indicate some sort of dialectical or individual, quirky speaking style.

I'm currently playing "Legend of Zelda: Spirit Tracks" (ゼルダの伝説・大地の汽笛) on the DS. In a rural town of woodcutters, they end most of their sentences with べ or っぺ. A village of Gorons (fictional race) end everything with ゴロ. Everyone encounters talking anime cats (or cat-eared people) that end with にゃ～ or にゃん. Rural jiisans end theirs with じゃ or じゃのう